# Is this a Positive Definite Matrix

Tags: matrices

Matrix $A$, $B$ and $C$ are symmetric Toeplitz matrices with $n$ by $n$ size, where $A$ and $C$ are positive definite matrices and $B$ or $(-B)$ is positive definite matrix, too. $R$ is a $2n$ by $2n$ matrix, and can be expressed as

$$R= \begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
B & C 
\end{pmatrix}$$

And one konwn condition is

[image]

For each number in these matrixes, it has

[image]

Is $R$ a positive definite matrix?

Comment: You keep on changing the conditions with time. How many times more are you going to do that? This is the third time (at least) you do it, and this is not serious. You should leave this alone and if you want you can ask a **new** question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider $A=I,\ B=2I$ and $C=\pmatrix{4&2\\ 2&4}$. Then  $B^2=4I<C=AC$ entrywise, but
$$\det(R)=\det(AC-B^2)=\det(C-4I)=\det\pmatrix{0&2\\ 2&0}<0.$$
From your edit history, I see that you have kept modifying the given conditions. Yet entrywise constraints are usually irrelavant in determining the definiteness of a matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Counterexample with $\,1\times 1\;$ matrices:

$$R=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\2&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Sorry, I forgot one known condition.

Comment: ...and you remember it 3 hours after you post your question and two hours after I post my answer...Anyway, Robert's counterexample **also** solves it.

Answer (score 1):

Try $$\pmatrix{1 & 2\cr 2 & 3\cr}$$

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. For adding konwn condition, is R a positive definite matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$A = C = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}, \quad B = {\rm I}_2.$$

Then all of them are symmetric positive definite and $b_{ij}^2 \le a_{ij}c_{ij} = a_{ij}^2$, but

$$R = \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ B & C \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$

is not, because $\det R = -5$.